# Binary classfication SVM giving one class value error despite two classes

Tags: python-2.7, machine-learning, scikit-learn, svm

I am using an RBF SVM on some data. My y data (classes) is as follows:

```
print len(y),y
```

returns:

```
120 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1]
```

Yet when I run this code to plot a learning curve I get a value error claiming there is only one class UPDATE: error has changed somewhat, check comments:

```
from sklearn.learning_curve import learning_curve

CV = cross_validation.StratifiedKFold(y, n_folds=10, shuffle = True)


def plot_learning_curve(estimator, title, X, y, ylim=None, cv=CV,
                    n_jobs=1, train_sizes=np.linspace(.1, 1.0, 5)):

    plt.figure()

    train_sizes, train_scores, test_scores = learning_curve(
       estimator, X, y, cv=cv, n_jobs=n_jobs, train_sizes=train_sizes)
    plt.grid()


    return plt






title = "Learning Curves (SVM, RBF kernel)"



plot_learning_curve(clf, title, val, y, cv=CV, n_jobs=1)

plt.show()
```

EDIT:After some changes to code, after some comments I have updated the code seen here

UPDATE: now this is the current state of the error:

`ValueError: The number of classes has to be greater than one; got 1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed to get it working, can't say I know the exact issue with the error. But it seems to come down to the train_sizes, despite using StratifiedKFold I think it was still ending up with test sets containing only 1 class. The way it's been fixed is simply to do alter the range of values in the train size until the error no longer appears!

I think it comes down to sample size and the number of folds, because even when you go below the range given by the error code, (by purposefully putting in training sizes that are greater than your sample size) it can still give that error above. I guessd that it'll be to do with the fact that the sample sizes can't always be split up perfectly?

Answer (score 0):

You are executing `learning_curve` with `cv` (cross-validation) set to `None` which falls back to the default 3-fold cross-validaiton (see [docs](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.learning_curve.learning_curve.html)). The reason why your code crashes most likely stems from the fact that there is a fold with only a single class.

You can pass your own cross-validation object to the `learning_curve` function (e.g. `StratifiedKFold`; see [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cross_validation.StratifiedKFold.html)) to avoid that error.

Comment: I think this is the solution, as it's solved another problem I was having. But I'm still getting the same error after switching to stratified k fold, as well as setting cv = cv inside the functions definition

Comment: *CV = cross_validation.StratifiedKFold(y, n_folds=10, shuffle = True)*

by the way

Comment: Have you tried iterating over the `StratifiedKFold` object and checked whether every fold contains 2 classes (just to make sure)?

Comment: I have using:
   for i, (train, test) in enumerate(CV):
        y_pred = clf.fit(val[train], y[train]).predict(val[test])
        print y_pred,"predicted"
        print y[test], "actual"

and there is some in every fold..

Comment: some of y_pred contain only one class however, that shouldn't  affect it though should it?

Comment: no, as long as there are both classes in `y[train]` its fine. As far as I can see now, your function `plot_learning_curve` declares a parameter `cv`, however when you _call_ `sklearns` `learning_curve` function you are passing `CV` into it. Given the signature for `plot_learning_curve` in your code above, the call for `learning_curve` should be: `learning_curve(estimator, X, y, cv=cv, n_jobs=n_jobs, train_sizes=train_sizes)` (Note `cv=cv` instead of `cv=CV`).

Comment: Now it says cv is not defined

Comment: ok, thats certainly odd, can you update your question to only contain your definition of the cross validation object, the call to your fn `plot_learning_curve`, and in `plot_learning_curve` only leave the call to `learning_curve`, that should make things clearer.

Comment: In my previous comment i meant to update the call to `learning_curve` not `plot_learning_curve`, `cv` (lowercase isnt defined outside the scope of `plot_learning_curve` thats why you see the `cv is not defined` error)

Comment: But when I change the call to `plot_learning_curve` to include cv = CV and with `learning_curve(
        estimator, X, y, cv=cv, n_jobs=n_jobs, train_sizes=train_sizes)` 

I get the original value error about the number of classes

Comment: it does sound very odd, have you stepwise debugged the whole code to see whats in `cv` and what arrives when the `fit` function on the classifier is called?

Comment: No I haven't, mainly because I'm not sure how to, can you suggest any that I could look at?

Comment: if you're using a python shell, you can use `pdb`, most IDE's (e.g. PyCharm) give you a step-by-step debugger UI.